Bluetooth mouse issue after reboot, Kubuntu 24.04
In 22.04 everything worked properly. After installing 24.04 (fresh installation) and pairing the mouse, it also works fine, but after restarting the system or turning Bluetooth off and on, the mouse does not work. Formally it is connected, but there is no data transmission (I installed blueman, because the transmission is shown there) and the cursor is stationary. There is also no information about the battery status, but this is probably due to the lack of transmission.
After removing the mouse and pairing it again, it works again until the next system reboot. Lenovo Yoga gen5, any mouse (same with three different ones). Same with the external Bluetooth adapter. Does anyone have similar effects and know what can be done about it?

Seems like it could be related to a power or driver issue - What are the outputs of sudo service bluetooth status and lsusb -tv?

Thank you for help! It turned out that the "service bluetooth status" showed errors.  It was caused by pairing my phone with my laptop. A very strange effect, it's the first time I've seen something like this.
